# Will the new angular 2 scoped NPM packages work with JSPM?

Tags: angular

wondering has anyone tried jspm with the new Angular 2 release candidate, specifically the new scoped npm packages ?

```
npm install --save @angular/core @angular/compiler @angular/common @angular/platform-browser @angular/platform-browser-dynamic rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 zone.js@0.6.12
```

and integrate it with jspm?

regards

Sean

Answer (score 1):

It works exactly like this with JSPM. I still have to install them with NPM, too, for my IDE to work correctly, but I think changes may be coming soon that would fix that issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

yes got it all working.

need to search and replace all imports for ng2

> ```
>  find ./ -type f -name "*.ts" -exec sed -i -e 's/angular2\/core/@angular\/core/g' {} \;
>     find ./ -type f -name "*.ts" -exec sed -i -e 's/angular2\/compiler/@angular\/compiler/g' {} \;
>     find ./ -type f -name "*.ts" -exec sed -i -e 's/angular2\/router/@angular\/router/g' {} \;
>     find ./ -type f -name "*.ts" -exec sed -i -e 's/angular2\/common/@angular\/common/g' {} \;
>     find ./ -type f -name "*.ts" -exec sed -i -e 's/angular2\/http/@angular\/http/g' {} \;
> ```

```
angular2/core -> @angular/core
angular2/compiler -> @angular/compiler
angular2/common -> @angular/common
angular2/platform/browser -> @angular/platform-browser (applications with precompiled templates) + @angular/platform-browser-dynamic (applications that compile templates on the fly)
angular2/platform/server -> @angular/platform-server
angular2/testing -> @angular/core/testing (it/describe/..) + @angular/compiler/testing (TestComponentBuilder) + @angular/platform-browser/testing
angular2/upgrade -> @angular/upgrade
angular2/http -> @angular/http
angular2/router -> @angular/router-deprecated (snapshot of the component router from beta.17 for backwards compatibility)
new package: @angular/router - component router with several breaking changes
```

and run:

```
npm install --save @angular/core @angular/compiler @angular/common @angular/platform-browser @angular/platform-browser-dynamic rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 zone.js@0.6.12
```

also you will need to make these changes:

RouterLink -> ROUTER_DIRECTIVES
RouteConfig -> Routes
RouteParams -> RouteSegment

RouteSegment has a different interface, use getParam(string) instead of get(string)

```
import {BrowserDomAdapter} from '@angular/platform-browser/src/browser/browser_adapter';
```

regards

Sean